# Text import into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, text, import

I have this code that helps with import of text files into excel. It intended to be a workaround for Excel not being able to deal with numbers longer than 15 characters.

I am trying to figure out a way to change this code .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1) into something that would go through a file an automatically check if a column contains numbers 16 characters or longer and automatically switch them to text values in order to preserve their formatting.

```
Sub Text_import()
Dim Ret

Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")

If Ret <> False Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

    .Name = "Sample"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Going by your description, your approach won't work. If long numbers are imported into Excel in a numerical format, then "switched back" to text, they will have already been corrupted. It won't be possible to recover the lost digits by switching the number "back." So you have to import the relevant columns strictly in text format.

Comment: Could we see an example of the .CSV file you are importing?

Comment: Well that's the thing, if it was a standard file, I could specify which columns should be treated as text. For example, if a file had order id's which are 16 digits and a total of 5 columns, this would work .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1). However, I was wondering if it was possible for vba to cycle through columns before importing a file to check if any of them were numeric and had more than 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Read the .CSV file in using ADO.

```
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Open
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .LoadFromFile ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\\tw_202103231726.txt"
    text = .ReadText(-1)
    .Close
    End With
```

then you have a text variable that you can process with VBA as you need.

Update:

maybe something like this -

```
    For ii = 1 To Len(text) Step 1

    Select Case Mid(text, ii, 2)
    Case Chr(34) & Chr(58) ' double quote 34 / colon 58

            dqcPos = InStr(ii + 3, text, Chr(34) & Chr(44)) ' double quote and comma
```